# Referring to Objective-C superclass variable

Tags: objective-c

I have a base class with some variables defined that looks something like:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    SomeObject *baz;
}

@implementation Foo
@synthesize baz;

// ...

@end

@interface Bar : Foo
@end

@implementation Bar

-(void)someMethod {
    NSString *foostr = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", baz];
}
```

I actually have a base class with about 30 subclasses.

The issue is that in most of them I can reference the base class' variable bad simply as baz but in a couple of sub-classes I have to explicitly reference bad as self.baz ...

Has anybody else seen this pathology?

Comment: Off topic but your example is littered with mistakes and formatting issues. If this is copied and pasted straight from source then maybe the mistakes needs addressing first.

Comment: When you say you can't reference "baz" are you talking about the lack of code-completion in xcode, or does it actually not compile?

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler is set to gcc, there's a bug: A subclass that defines a @property without a corresponding ivar definition (which is perfectly legal) hides any superclass ivars.

Solution: Switch your compiler to LLVM.

(If that solution isn't feasible for some reason, the fallback is what you discovered: Use messaging instead of direct reference.)

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks - I will not pull out what remains of my hair. John